# Is it possible to answer an http request sent to a local network broadcast address?

Tags: http, networking, broadcast

If I open a browser and send a request to http://255.255.255.255, is it possible have a web server, on the same subnet, listening and respond?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) servers use the [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) protocol, and broadcast packets can only be sent through the stateless [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) protocol.

Quoting [W. Richard Stevens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Richard_Stevens) from his classic book [TCP/IP Illustrated](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633469) (Chapter 12):

> Broadcasting and multicasting only apply to UDP, where it makes sense for an application to send a single message to multiple recipients. TCP is a connection-oriented protocol that implies a connection between two hosts (specified by IP addresses) and one process on each host (specified by port numbers).

So, I guess the answer is no.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I've done discovery via UDP Multicast, but wasn't sure if TCP was possible over broadcast, thanks again.